# Open Graph actions not appearing on ticker

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm posting a graph action for which I receive an activity ID - meaning the api call was successful. But the action doesn't appear on the ticker. I can see it in my activity log but I assume no one else can since I have to click on 'shown on timeline' to get it to appear. I'm not looking to make it appear on the timeline, just the ticker should be enough.

Comment: Please refer to my response here - http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/12360866/1628782

Comment: thanks! so its just a matter of waiting for higher volumes

Comment: Did this ever work? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: We are also seeing the same problem: open graph posts from our iphone app stopped appearing in the recent activity box and in the ticker. I have a theory this is because we've started asking for post permissions right after account info permissions at all times, going against FB best practices guidelines. Anyone else experience this?